What is the "Forward voltage drop of the ringback rectifier" in an impulse power supply IC?
I have been looking at various impulse power supply ICs and most of the ones that I've found (e.g. MC34063A: https://www.rcscomponents.kiev.ua/datasheets/MC34063A.pdf) require me to know a value of the "Forward voltage drop of the ringback rectifier" for the calculations. I asked both plain Google and Copilot about this value and neither have yielded any useful results. No such term in the "The Art of Electronics" either. What's even more confusing is the fact that this value is listed along the ones which are inherent to the IC itself, but I can't find its value anywhere in the datasheets. What is it exactly?

Please link the datasheet into your question.

Just did that. Thanks. Duplicating it here too just in case: https://www.rcscomponents.kiev.ua/datasheets/MC34063A.pdf

They mean the flyback rectifier: -

Flyback rectifier in the example of a buck (step-down) regulator: -

It's much clearer in the ON semi data sheet for the same device: -

